# Find the conditions required for the values of a, b, and c that make the following matrix symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Set up the system:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 5&  a+b+c&  a-b \\
                      3&   -7&   2\\
                      1&     a+c  & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

I did it like this: \begin{bmatrix} 5&  3&  1 \\
                                    3&   -7&   a+c\\
                                    1&     a+c  & 6 \end{bmatrix}

Did I answer the question correctly? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The questions ask for conditions on the constants. What is your answer? I just see a matrix (and it's not clear how you got it?)

Comment: Symmetric implies $A = A^{T}$.

Comment: Next time go with a more appropriate title...

Comment: @Kaj_H The post had been vandalized.

Comment: Interesting.  Well it's good it got cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

You have not solved for $a$, $b$ and $c$. As you have right observed, we need $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$ for the matrix to be symmetric. Hence, we need
$$a+b+c = 3$$
$$a-b = 1$$
$$a+c = 2$$
You have three equations in three unknowns. Solve for $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve a linear system with euqations

a + b + c = 3

a - b = 1

a + c = 2

Answer (score 0):

To find the conditions you must have

\begin{bmatrix} 5&  a+b+c&  a-b \\
                      3&   -7&   2\\
                      1&     a+c  & 6 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 5&  3&  1 \\
                                    3&   -7&   a+c\\
                                    1&     a+c  & 6 \end{bmatrix}.

This gives $a+b+c=3$, $a-b=1$ and $a+c=2$. This would give $a=2$,$b=1$ and $c=0$.